# Queue manager for API requests in PHP

Tags: php, message-queue, priority-queue

I am developing a REST API in Laravel that can be called through Curl.

The API's purpose is generating files based on the request params and giving back those files in the JSON response as a base64 string. The generation process is heavily influenced by the size of these files (ranging from 0.5Mb to 30Mb). The whole process (from request to response) can take from 1 sec up to 2 minutes in average.

These HTTP requests should be handled by a Queue Manager (eg. gearman) which can handle a priority queue. This manager should be able to assign 2-3 workers for load balancing. One worker for the largest file in the queue and 1-2 workers for the smaller ones.

My problem is, that these requests are not like a typical mail queue for example, where you can queue the request and a background job will process it. I have to give back the resulting files as soon as I have them and in the same response.

How exactly would you implement a queue in this situation? I have looked at gearman for example, but I do not understand how to give back the results in the same HTTP response.

(Sorry if my question is not clear, I will try to update it if needed...)

Update:

I need a queue because there can be a huge amount of clients requesting a lot of files at the same time and the server would crash after a couple of large requests running at the same time. 
1. There can only be a small amount of simultaneus running processes (max. 3)
2. No process can be lost due to maxing out server memory or CPU power
3. Priorities should be enforced on the queue to be fair to small processes which can be served in seconds compared to large ones which can be served in minutes.

How am I able to serve these requests and also have this queue? That is my question.

Comment: Can you predict ahead of time how long the job will take?  What is the *role* of the queue manager?  To ensure fariness? To make sure long jobs happen eventually, slowly, not at all? To make sure fast jobs don't clog the pipeline?

Comment: If it is the same HTTP response, then there is no queue. Which makes your question pretty unclear. What was it again?

Comment: I have updated my question to be more clear about the queue.

Comment: @Charles - I cannot predict, only assume that larger files will take a lot longer to process. But my problem is not with setting up a queue for my jobs, but how to give back the results in a REST API environment.

Comment: So let's say you have three background workers, and there's a queue thirty requests long with jobs that take two minutes.  A request submitted now is going to take *at least* twenty minutes for a request that goes in now to be served.  The normal HTTP timeout is five minutes, and even that's stretching it if the client is a browser.  You may need to rethink the *requirement* that all user requests get same-connection results.  There's no shame in handing out an IOU ticket and asking the client to check back later.

Comment: @Charles This helps, but does not solve my case. I will try to find a solution and post it up here. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: @Charles Hey Charles this is basically what you have described: http://www.adayinthelifeof.nl/2011/06/02/asynchronous-operations-in-rest/ I am going to implement something similar. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it! :)

Comment: @GergelyHavlicsek, that's a pretty clever reuse of HTTP right there... but not my style.  There's no shame in a self-answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method described here is a nice example what to do in my case: http://www.adayinthelifeof.nl/2011/06/02/asynchronous-operations-in-rest/